# Removing the hompage url title

Tags: c1-cms

Is it possible to remove the homepage url title in the new 5.0 version of composite? meaning the frontpage title.

In older versions of C1 there was a URL configuration setting under the system tab
where you could unchek "Include homepage URL title"

So what I want is to have: www.my-domain.com/gallery instead of www.my-domain.com/frontpage/gallery

Answer (score 1):

You need to restore these 4 files, then you'll get UrlConfiguration back into the Console like before version 5.0.

That is, download the files and copy them into the same location.

[/Composite/Composite/content/forms/Administrative/Hostnames.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS/e812caaee19c473f3e13719aad45ec6529df88af/Website/Composite/content/forms/Administrative/Hostnames.xml)
[/Composite/content/forms/Administrative/UrlConfiguration.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS/e812caaee19c473f3e13719aad45ec6529df88af/Website/Composite/content/forms/Administrative/UrlConfiguration.xml)
[/Composite/localization/Composite.Web.UrlConfiguration.en-us.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS/e812caaee19c473f3e13719aad45ec6529df88af/Website/Composite/localization/Composite.Web.UrlConfiguration.en-us.xml)'
[/App_Data/Composite/TreeDefinitions/UrlConfiguration.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS/e812caaee19c473f3e13719aad45ec6529df88af/Website/App_Data/Composite/TreeDefinitions/UrlConfiguration.xml)

The files were removed during [this commit](https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS/commit/31415aa5231397312e226320f994b9683b87da73) and what you need to do is basically just to revert the changes.

Comment: Thanx, that did it. You write 5 files, but there's only 4. Guess that was a typo?

Comment: Yup, a typo - the files were removed here https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS/commit/31415aa5231397312e226320f994b9683b87da73 and what you need to do is basically just to revert the commit.

Comment: @jna can you accept the answer if it fulfilled your needs.